# Ayuda con un metodo menu en java

Tags: java

Soy nuevo programando aprendi unas cuantas cosas en C# y pues quiero hacer un metodo menu para que me muestre los datos que llene, pero no se como enviar los datos de otro metodo al metodo **Menu()**, talvez me explique remal pero aqui esta el codigo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Creacuenta Obj = new Creacuenta();
}
```

Despues de ir a la clase creacuenta llamo al metodo **CrearCuenta()**

```
public class Creacuenta {
public Creacuenta(){

Crearcuenta();

Menu();
}
```

en el metodo **CrearCuenta()** pido cuantas cuentas ingresar, hago un ciclo for las lleno lleno todos los datos y devuelvo una cadena de tipo String

```
public String Crearcuenta(){
String Nombre,NombreCuenta="",cadena="";
int Identidad,Tipo,Numcuen,mes;
double DineroIng;
// creo una lista donde se guardaran los datos  

Cuenta[] lista = new Cuenta[Numcuen];
// creo un objeto cue donde se almaneceran los datos de cada cuenta

Cuenta cue;
//comienzo el llenado de cada cuenta con un ciclo for

for(int i = 1; i<= Numcuen;i++){
 // lleno todos los datos y los envio 
 cue = new Cuenta(Nombre,DineroIng,Identidad,NombreCuenta);

 // lleno la lista
  lista[i-1] = cue;
 } 
 // luego hago un ciclo for para crear la cadena
 for(int i=0; i<lista.length;i++){

   cadena +="\n Cuenta"+(i+1)+  " de  :\t "+lista[i].getNombre()+" \n Cedula 
    : \t"+ lista[i].getId()+ "\ntipo : \t" +lista[i].getTiposcu() +"\n Saldo 
     actual  : \t"+lista[i].getDinero()+"\n  ///////////////////////////// 
    ";

 return cadena}
```

y en el metodo **Menu()** quiero mostrar los datos de la cadena que retorne

```
 public void Menu(){
   int Codigo; 
 Codigo = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Bienvenido al menu 
  Digite a donde quieres ir \n 1) Ver Cuenta \n 2) Retirar dinero \n 3) 
 Salir")); 


 if(Codigo==1){

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saldo de las cuentas" );
}
```

y pues no se que hacer para enviar los datos a **Menu()** y pues trato de hacer esto pero el despues de terminar el metodo **Crearcuenta()** el codigo me ejecuta **Algo= Crearcuenta()** y se vuelvo a llenar los datos.

```
public class Creacuenta {
public Creacuenta(){

String algo;

Crearcuenta();

algo = Crearcuenta();

Menu(algo);


}

public void Menu(String algo){
```

En si mi duda es como puedo mandar la cadena que hice en el metodo **Crearcuenta()** al metodo **Menu()** para utilizarla y mostrarlao si se puede hacer mas facil, inicialmente el metodo **Crearcuenta()** era para el llenado de las cuentas y no retornaba nada `public void Crearcuenta(){ // hacia lo mismo pero no retornaba la cadena}`  pero quise hacer un menu y pues me perdi un poco

Comment: No se como se hace en C# pero debes aprender como te han dicho a partir el codigo en pedazos. Piensa en un objeto cuenta que quieres que tenga pues un id y una clave creas la clase cuenta con esos atributos, que quieres que tenga una persona y una clave pues creas una clase persona con sus atributos y una clase cuenta con un atributo objeto persona y un atributo clave

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres mandar la cadena al método menu(), entonces pasale como parametro al método la cadena

```
  public void menu(String cadena){
   }
```

Pero dejame darte un consejo, mejor usa clases para manipular los datos, a partir de tus clases puedes crear objetos del tipo de tu clase y esos objetos tendran los atributos de tu clase

te dare un ejemplo de una clase

```
 public class persona(){
  //primero escribe los atributos de tu clase
  private String nombre;
  private int    edad;
  private String sexo;

   //Tu clase contendra estos atributos y cuando creas un objeto del tipo de tu clase este heredara los atributos

  }
```

Entonces en tu programa principal instancias tus objetos

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   persona persona1 = new persona("Jorgue",21,"Masculino")//en esta parte le paso los atributos al objeto "persona1" de la clase "persona"
   //entonces si queremos acceder a los datos que estan en el objeto "persona1" sería de la siguiente forma
     persona1.getNombre();
     persona1.getEdad();
     persona1.getSexo(); //ojo aqui solo hago uso del metodo get para acceder a los atributos que tiene la persona1, no los estoy mostrando en pantalla
  }
```

En este ejemplo solo muestro como guardar datos para una sola persona pero también puedes hacer un arreglo de clases, ya seria cosa de que investigaras por tu cuenta, si eres nuevo te recomiendo veas un curso de POO (Programación Orientada a Objetos)

Saludos.